# Elasticsearch Parse Exception for boolean queries

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene, kibana, phrase

I'm trying to create queries similar to kibana queries in elasticsearch lucene queries. What I'm basically trying to do is matching some phrases. For example; my kibana query looks like this:(+"anna smith") AND ( (+"university"), (+"chairman"), (+"women rights")) It searches "anna smith" as must and one of the other phrases as should(there should be at least one of them exist in the text). I wrote a query to do this but it gives "elasticsearch parse exception:expected field name but got start_object". How can I solve this. Here is my query;

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": {
                "match": {  
                    "text": {
                        "query":    "anna smith",
                        "operator": "and"
                    }
                }
              }
            },
             "query": {
                "bool": {
                    "must": [
                    {
                    "bool": {
                    "should": [
                        { 
                            "match": {
                            "text": {
                                "query": "university",
                                "boost": 2 
                            }
                        }

                        },
                        { 
                            "match": {
                            "text": {
                                "query": "chairman",
                                "boost": 2 
                                    }
                                  }
                        }
            ]
        }
    }]
}}}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second query at the bottom cannot be there, it needs to be inside the first `bool/must` like this

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "text": {
              "query": "anna smith",
              "operator": "and"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "should": [
              {
                "match": {
                  "text": {
                    "query": "university",
                    "boost": 2
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                "match": {
                  "text": {
                    "query": "chairman",
                    "boost": 2
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```